# Deserialize XML CData with attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have an xml file and I try to write a type for it.
At a certain point my brain freezes.

This xml is as minimal as I can write it.

```
<Level ID="SomeID">
    <Selection Name="AnotherID">
        <Content><![CDATA[SomeData]]></Content>
    </Selection>
</Level>
```

In cs I want to write a class as a type for the xmlserializer.

```
public class Level
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public ??? Selection {get; set;}
    //What is the type of CDATA
    //Where would the Name Attribute go?
}
```

Somehow the Selection has to be a class with an attribute and also the type of Selection is CData. Whatever CData is it would be a standard type and so I could not set the `Name` Attribute.

How do I resolve this in the cs class? - the xml is legacy and can not be changed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good start there..  this should help you get the rest of the way.

```
public class Level
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ID {get; set;}
    public Selection Selection {get; set;}
}

public class Selection {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Content Content {get;set;}
}

public class Content {
    [XmlText]
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

So to access that CDATA text via your object model you would access `Level.Selection.Content.Data`.